# Backbone: Accessing models attributes recently set across methods

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views

I'm facing a weird behavior with my backbone views and models. Out of full collection, I make a dummy one where the models are containers for group of models from the full one conditionally. This works really fine but ... when I set some attributes to the dummy models, they are accessible only from the current view's method (where the attr are set) but not in other methods.

```
Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function () {
        // Intitialze the filtered collection whatever way.
    },
    method1: function () {
        // Executed 1st.
        this.filteredCollection.each(function (model) {
            model.set({
                "attr": "any value"
            });
        });

        this.filteredCollection.models[0].get("attr");  // is defined.
    },
    method2: function () {
        // Executed 2nd.
        this.filteredCollection.models[0].get("attr");  // is undefined.
    }
});
```

I'm completely lost as this isn't the way (I understood) the objects are supposed to work.

Comment: It should work correctly. You have to check some others code parts that could modify the collection.

Comment: How are method1 and method2 being called?

Comment: I think I had a problem with an intermediate code. Since I moved everything inside the view it works.